# Django channels, running server not working

Tags: python, django, chat, channel

I am trying to make a chat webapp with django and channels and now that I have integrated channels into the project I am getting this trace back error

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
File ".\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\channels\apps.py", line 6, in <module>
    import daphne.server
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\daphne\server.py", line 18, in <module>
    asyncioreactor.install()
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\asyncioreactor.py", line 320, in install
PS C:\Users\abdsak11\OneDrive - Lärande\Dokument\GitHub\django-chat\djangoChat> py.exe .\manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\channels\apps.py", line 6, in <module>
    import daphne.server
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\daphne\server.py", line 18, in <module>
    asyncioreactor.install()
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\asyncioreactor.py", line 320, in install
    reactor = AsyncioSelectorReactor(eventloop)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\asyncioreactor.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__()
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 571, in __init__
    self.installWaker()
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 286, in installWaker
    self.addReader(self.waker)
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\asyncioreactor.py", line 151, in addReader
    self._asyncioEventloop.add_reader(fd, callWithLogger, reader,
File "C:\Users\abdsak11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

i am following the tutorial that you can find here in the channels website: [tutorial website](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html) but still this is not working.
i tried migrating the project and it didnt work, i changed the app name in the settings.py file but still nothing is working

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for djangoChat project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@*82aa8a64&jzmqz6qj3v0@d==a(4vwuise_$@w709)8r_cx30'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'chat',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoChat.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoChat.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoChat.routing.application'



# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**Viwes.py (app)**

```
# chat/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/index.html', {})
```

**routing.py**

```
# mysite/routing.py
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
})
```

**urls.py (app)**

```
# chat/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'chat'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Fine that you posted your error trace, but where is your code? Thank you.

Comment: @powerPixie sorry forgot to include it. I just did it by the way, thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Which OS are you using? Have you got any solutions yet?

Comment: @rahim.nagori Windows, or what do you mean ?

Comment: I have the similar/same problem now. Did you find any solution?